# How to find number of bars in amcharts 4 graph?

Tags: graph, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

[image: Sample chart]
I have built a chart using amcharts 4 and want to add if-else statement based on the number of columns/bars
I want to make statements like

```
if(number of columns > 20)
{do something}
```

Is there a way to get the total number of bars?

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of data like this:

```
 var chart = am4core.create("chart", am4charts.XYChart); 
 if (chart.data.length >20){
  //do smt.
 }
```